# Spackling drywalls around plumbing pipes

Tags: plumbing, patching-drywall, hole-repair, spackling-paste, foam

What’s the best way to fix drywall holes ~1-1.5” on each side around pipes coming into the wall under sink. I’ve seen folks foam the holes around pipes, but it looks ugly. I was thinking to patch with spackling patch, but this would most likely crack if any force is applied to the pipe to connect/ disconnect faucet etc, or by accidentally impacting the pipe under a sink. ‍♂️

[image: pipe hole]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sounds like you want a **escutcheon**, which is a metal (usually) trim part designed to cover the hole between the pipe and the wall.

I generally just put some mesh drywall tape and hot (setting-type) mud (joint compound, not spackle) there, if I'm going for "slow down the mice" rather than "pretty." For "pretty" you want a escutcheon. If you have the pipes already in place, you'll want a hinged one that does not require disconnecting pipes to get it in place.

Comment: You'll want drywall for fire/mouse reasons PLUS an escutcheon for appearance.  A split escutcheon for retrofit situations.

Answer (score 5):

HVAC duct sealant will be the easiest and it is paintable and flexible when dry.  I wish I discovered the stuff much earlier in life.  I would use that with fiberglass tape.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid cracking use drywall MESH tape.

Made from fiberglass strings, so it will not break.

Mud it generously.

It is self adhesive to keep it in place while applying mud.

[image: tape]